# How to find value of every element under one parent element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have following HTML. Using jQuery, I want get the value of each HTML element under `<dl class="item-options">` in one variable.

The `<dl class="item-options">` is being generated in a table multiple time every time having different  values under `<dl class="item-options">`

```
<dl class="item-options">
        <dd class="truncated" style="color:red;">DSOX3000-232, RS232/UART Serial Decode and Trigger - in <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Software Applications</dt><dd id="pppp">DSOX3000-232, RS232/UART Serial Decode and Trigger - installed, DSOX3000-AMS, CAN and LIN Automotive Serial Decode - installed, DSOX3000-MAT, Advanced Math Analysis for Infiniivision Oscilloscopes - installed, DSOX3000-VID, Enhanced Video/TV Application Package - installed/</dd></dl></div>
        </dd>          

        <div class="mdata">
            <dd class="truncated">DSOX3000-001, WaveGen 20 MHz Function/Arbitrary Wavefor <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Advanced Analysis</dt><dd id="pppp">DSOX3000-001, WaveGen 20 MHz Function/Arbitrary Waveform Generator - installed/</dd></dl></div></dd>
        </div>          

        <div class="mdata">
            <dd>DSOX3000-040, Memory Upgrade - 4 Mpts of MegaZoom IV/</dd>
        </div>          

        <div class="mdata">
            <dd class="truncated">DSOX3000-805, Module - LAN/VGA, DSOX3000-806, Module -  <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Connectivity</dt><dd id="pppp">DSOX3000-805, Module - LAN/VGA, DSOX3000-806, Module - GPIB/</dd></dl></div></dd>
        </div>          

        <div class="mdata">
            <dd class="truncated">DSO0000-903, Power cord - United States and Canada 120V <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Power Cords</dt><dd id="pppp">DSO0000-903, Power cord - United States and Canada 120V, NEMA 5-15P male plug/</dd></dl></div></dd>
        </div>          

        <div class="mdata">
            <dd class="truncated">DSOX3000-A6J, Certificate of compliance calibration - A <a onclick="return false" class="dots" href="#">...</a>/<div class="truncated_full_value"><dl class="item-options"><dt>Calibration - Upgrade Commercial Calibration Certificate</dt><dd id="pppp">DSOX3000-A6J, Certificate of compliance calibration - ANSI Z540, printed/</dd></dl></div></dd>
        </div>          

        <p style="margin-top:37px"></p>
            <dd>R-50C-021-5, ANSI Z540-1-1994 Calibration - 5 years</dd>
        <p></p>          

        <p style="margin-top:10px"></p>
            <dd>R-51B-001-5F, Return to Agilent Warranty - 5 years</dd><p>
        </p>              
</dl>
```

I am using following code to select all elements' values which are under `<dl class="item-options">`:

```
$(".item-options").each(function() {    
                description+=$(".mdata").find("*").html();  
});
```

But I am unable to fetch all values. What is the correct way to do this?

I want the values in html format so when I display these values in a popup.It shoul retain look and feel.

Comment: Can you post an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Terence actually When I hover on <dl class="item-options"> I want all the  children elements to be shown in a popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as you are selecting the same elements in each iteration. If you need the text contents, you can use jQuery `text` method or `textContent` property.

```
var text = $(".item-options").children().map(function() {
       return $(this).text(); 
}).get().join('');
```

`map` method returns an array, you can convert it to a string using Array object's `join` method.

Comment: I want values of each html element under <dl class="item-options">

Answer (score 1):

use `children()`

try ths

```
 $(".item-options").children(".mdata").each(function() {    
      description+=$(this).html();  
 });
```